# ActsAsTaggableOn after own tag implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I had my own implementation of tags in my rails application and wanted to replace it by the ActsAsTaggableOn gem. I generated the migration and deleted all the migrations with tags in it, but forgot to rollback first, so I just did rake db:reset. Now the schema looks fine with tag and taggable in it, but if I try Tags out in the Console, by just typing Tag i get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Tag
```

What causes this error, I thought I just did like in the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?autoplay=true).

My schema.rb looks like this:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended to check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121009203921) do

  create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "message_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "start_at"
    t.datetime "end_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       :limit => 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], :name => "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], :name => "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password"
    t.string   "salt"
    t.boolean  "admin",              :default => false
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "street"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.string   "location"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true

end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to have a model, to get it work in the console.